# GWT 2.8.2 compiler exception

Tags: java, gwt, compiler-errors, runtime-error

com.google.gwt.dev.PrecompilationContextCreator$1.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(PrecompilationContextCreator.java:86)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:519)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:487)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.maybeHandleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:415)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.visit(UnifyAst.java:402)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:265)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
... 45 more
[ERROR] at GridView.java(1351): GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
[ERROR] at GridView.java(1351): (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
[ERROR] at GridView.java(1351): this.templates = (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBinaryOperation
[ERROR] at GridView.java(1351): this.templates = (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class)
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JExpressionStatement
[ERROR] at GridView.java(1350): {
this.templates = (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class);
}
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
[ERROR] at GridView.java(1350): {
this.templates = (GridTemplates) GWT.create(GridTemplates.class);
}
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
[ERROR] at GridView.java(1350): com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.GridView.initTemplates()V
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod

Comment: Can you share the rest of the error log, before this message?

Comment: I posted full here: https://pastebin.com/t4QT1VHa

Comment: Your log says there were 82 files that didn't compile at all, but were ignored due to not being in strict mode. I'd suggest starting there and fixing that, but the next error is `[ERROR] Line 322: The method append(boolean) is ambiguous for the type StringBuffer`, which doesn't make any sense. Check that you correctly updated all GWT dependencies, and you don't accidentally have an old copy of 2.8.1 or before in your project.

Comment: My project was running with gwt 2.1.1 and updated to 2.8.2. After I did the update does not compile and gives those errors there, can you help me?

Comment: You have some type casting errors to fix-- check Line 548: Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element to com.google.gwt.user.client.Element

Answer (score 0):

What version of GXT are you using? When updating from 2.0-2.1 to 2.2 and beyond, there is a custom GXT 2 jar that must be used, labeled gxt-version-gwt22.jar, so that it works correctly. You may well have other jars on your classpath that needs updating (and should be documented as such) to correctly move to the latest.

For example, if using gxt 2.3.1, you'll need to switch from the gxt-2.3.1.jar to gxt-2.3.1-gwt22.jar. If you are using a version of GXT 2 older than 2.2.0, you may simply need to update to a newer version of GXT before continuing.

Comment: Hi Colin, sorry for bombing here :) I lost couple of days now and cannot find why Im getting the same exception. I tried to move from gwt2.5 to gwt 2.8. In 2.5 I used gxt2.2.5-gwt22.jar with 2.8 and same gxt Im getting  the exact same error, method is ambiguous. Tried also with gxt.2.3.1 and gxt.2.3.1a-gwt22.jar but same error..

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the project, but you have some incompatible jars of some kind. Make sure to clean the project (gwt-unitCache, etc), make sure to check dependencies (if using maven, `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and look for something other than 2.8.2), make sure only one copy of gwt-user/gwt-dev/gxt on your classpath, etc. https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt is chat for GWT stuff, or shoot me an email colin@vertispan.com. Also consider creating your own question, with full details (dependency details, updated log, etc), i check SO a few times per day.

Comment: Thank u for the prompt reply, I send email to you directly, was the easiest for me. Tnx :)